# AlertDialog dynamically call next dialog with buttonclick with data read from LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, android

I want to do something like a getNext() call on the LinkedHashMap and send the data into the create_dialog_method. I read about using Iterator on the hashmap and some counter that keeps tracks of the next position. I'm not sure how to do it codewise though.

Here is the Activity for the dialogues:
public class QuestionsActivity extends Activity {

```
Map<String, Boolean> question_map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Boolean>();


//ArrayList<Questions> question_array = new ArrayList<Metrics>();

int counter = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);

    //false = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button NO
    //true  = call showRiskEvaluationDialog() on button YES
    question_map.put("8. Question8?", false);
    question_map.put("7. Question7?", false);
    question_map.put("6. Question6?", false);
    question_map.put("5. Question5?", false);
    question_map.put("4. Question4?", false);
    question_map.put("3. Question3?", false);
    question_map.put("2. Question2?", false);
    question_map.put("1. Question1?", false);


    create_dialog_method("asd2313", false);


    // For loop to extract a question and identifier from the Map


    //for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry : question_map.entrySet()){
    //   create_dialog_method(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    //}//end for


}//end onCreate()




/**
 * Method for creating a dialog window that show question and two buttons.
 * @param question_param
 * @param identifier
 */
public void create_dialog_method(String question_param, final boolean identifier) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title");
    alert.setMessage(question_param);

    alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

          if (identifier)

              showRiskEvaluationDialog();
          else 

              //**********HERE IS THE PROBLEM********
              if (identifier == false);

              for (Entry<String, Boolean> entry:  question_map.entrySet()){
                  create_dialog_method(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
                  break;

              }


             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

          if (identifier)
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved",
                      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          else

          showRiskEvaluationDialog();
       }
    });
    alert.show();
 }
```

Comment: Why not just show the next question in your dialogs onClick? When you are finished with a question, you clicked one of the dialog buttons...so fire up the next question.

Comment: @ElDuderino yeah that's what I want to do, is there a way to do a loop that sends data from one row at a time from the linkedhashmap into the create_dialog_method when a dialog button is pressed?